# Java のクラス継承で分からない箇所がある

Tags: java

Java初心者です。クラス継承の問題でわからない問題があります。ご教授ください

> 問題文：
> Comicクラスを継承したShortComicクラスを作りましょう。ShortComicは，1巻しか出てないコミック本を表します。ShortComicクラスには以下の実装を行います。
>
> - 文字列型のシリーズ名のみを受け取るコンストラクタを持つ
> - 継承元のコンストラクタの巻数には1を指定する
>
> ShortComicクラスはbookパッケージに定義するものとし（ShortComic.javaは適切なディレクトリにあります），パッケージ外からアクセスできなければなりません

書いたプログラム：

```
import book.Comic;
public  class ShortComic extends Comic {

public void Comic(String series) {
    super();
    this.volume = 1;
    }
}
```

エラー内容：

```
error: constructor Comic in class Comic cannot be applied to given types;
public  class ShortComic extends Comic {
        ^
  required: String,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

book/ShortComic.java:24: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
        super();
             ^

book/ShortComic.java:25: error: volume has private access in Comic
    this.volume = 1;
        ^
3 errors
```

このようなエラーが出てきているのですがさっぱりわかりません。間違っているところがあったら教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

> error: constructor Comic in class Comic cannot be applied to given types;
> error: call to super must be first statement in constructor

これは、`ShortComic` クラスに適切なコンストラクタがないことで起きてます。

> `public void Comic(String series) {`

`public ShortComic(String series) {` でしょう。

---

> error: volume has private access in Comic

問題文には`volume`フィールドに代入しろとは書いてないですよね。

> 継承元のコンストラクタの巻数には1を指定する

コンストラクタに`1`を渡すのでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

`Comic` クラスは次のような形なのかと思われます:

```java
package book;

public class Comic {

    private final String series;
    private final int volume;

    public Comic(String series, int volume) {
        this.series = series;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    // ...
}
```

この場合、課題を満たす `ShortComic` の実装は次のようになります:

```java
package book;

public class ShortComic extends Comic {

    public ShortComic(String series) {
        super(series, 1);
    }
}
```

- コンストラクタの名前はクラス名と同じです(今回の場合は`ShortComic`)。
- `super(...);` というのは親クラスのコンストラクタ(ここでは`public Comic(String series, int volume){...}`)呼び出しです。なので、引数に何を渡すかは親コンストラクタに合わせる必要があります。

  - つまり、今回の場合、第1引数にシリーズ名、第2引数に巻数を設定することになります。